# Is This possible to add channels inside of a fabric channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am new to **hyperledger fabric**. Is there a way to make channels under a channel. Normally, all channels are under system channel. But is this possible to make another channel which is governed by an intermediate channel not the system channel. And if this is possible then who should be responsible to create the channel in the bottom of the channel hierarchy.

=> System Channel governs Intermediate channels. An Intermediate channel can cover another channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A channel is a logical construct where a subset of network orgs can transact without all the non channel orgs knowing about the transactions.  For instance, if a network has 5 orgs: A, B, C, D, & E, you could have a channelAB with organisation A and B in the channel, and any transactions between A&B via ChannelAB would be stored in the Ledger associated with ChannelAB.  Organization C, D and E would not have access to those transactions unless they also became members of that channel.

The System Channel governing all the intermediate (aka application) channels is a way to say the system channel comes first and is leveraged to create an application channel, to set up policies, etc.

Help me understand what you are trying to do where you need a hierarchy of channels?

Comment: It's like, any city is governed in a hierarchical manner. Thus, is there any way to accomplish this type of pattern in a fabric blockchain. Can I view each intermediate channel as a city?

Comment: I see what you mean.  Channels are not so much like cities to states to country, channels are more like roads so they won't fit into a hierarchical flow like you want to do.  You might be able to use a combination of Orgs, Consortiums, Channels and Private Data Collections for hierarchy. . I would recommend reading up on PDCs to see what's doable here:  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data/private-data.html